# Searching for a member with an ID ( ID example: AVC/ENE/003 ) in Laravel. But the Laravel 'LIKE' feature does not support all the features I need

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Basically I want to be able to query my Laravel MySQL database and get a member details based on the ID provided on the search form. I am currently using the Laravel 'LIKE' feature for this query but it isn't just enough.

For example, i have a member with the ID of AVC/"A"DIVWARRI/0059 . I only want to display this member details when the input search matches all of the string characters or letters and also want it to be case sensitive too. ( for example , do not display user data even though the id is the same but in lowercase `avc/"a"divwarri/0059` .

With the Laravel 'LIKE' feature even though I only input the word 'DIV' which is a part of the whole member ID AVC/"A"DIVWARRI/0059 , it still gets to show the member details , of which I do not want

This is the code I am using below for the controller . How can I improve on this to meet my needs??

```
public function id_check(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;

    $member = Member::when($id, function ($query, $id) {
        return $query->where('id_no', 'like', "%$id%")->get();
    });


    if ($member->isEmpty()) {
        return view('home.notfound');
        
    } else {
        return view('home.id_verification', [
            'member' => $member
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... don't use `LIKE` then .... it sounds like you want an exact match? `"I only want to display this member details when the input search matches all of the string characters or letters and also want it to be case sensitive too."` ... that would just be an exact match .... ?

Comment: Elaborate more on how i can use it on my query

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, think you need the equal operator to match the exact string like this:

```
$query->where('id_no', '=', $id)->get();
```

**Update**

to match the case sensitive strings you can try to use the Binary conversion of the field like this:

```
$query->where(DB::raw('BINARY `id_no`') '=', $id)->get();
```

Comment: When i try this , no results are then shown..

Comment: If you print the $query in sql using the `toSql` method wat will ti returns ?

Comment: Ok IT WORKS.. But does not work in the case sensitive scenario. How can i achieve that?

Comment: To achive this you can try to convert the field in his binary form. I've updated the answer in order to give you an example of what i mean.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to force a case sensitive search using like because your collation is already case insensitive, simply cast it as binary:

```
$query->where('id_no', 'like binary', "%$id%")->get();
```

If you want to only match the last name (example DIVWARRI) based on your format of `AVC/"A"DIVWARRI/0059` then something like this should work:

```
$query->where('id_no', 'like binary', "%/\"%\"$id/%")->get();
```